# Python Regex match only where every word is capitalized

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match all strings where all words are capitilized.

At the moment I have tried something like this:

```py
list = ["This sentence should Not Match", "This Should Only Match"]
match = []
for l in list:
   x = re.search("^[A-Z]*.", l)
   if x:
      match.append(l)
```

For example I would like the regex to match only something like: "This Is A Good Example Here", but it should not match: "Something like this Here", "HERE Is an example that Should NOT Match", "TiHiS SeNtEnEcE" or "This Should NOT Match.Foo"

I am looping over lots of news articles and trying to match all the titles. These titles usually have every word capitalized.

Comment: What about "TiHiS SeNtEnEcE"?

Comment: Should not match "TiHiS SeNtEnEcE". Should only match something like: "This Is Another Example Here"

Comment: @TambetTamm what about this `This Should Only Match.Foo`

Comment: @AvinashRaj should not match with that.

Comment: @TambetTamm I hope the accepted answer does the \matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I support Chris' solution foremost, but here's a possible regex approach:

```
import re

sentences = ["This sentence should Not Match", "This Should Only Match"]
result = [x for x in sentences if re.match(r"^([A-Z][a-z]*\b\s*)+$", x)]
print(result) # => ["This Should Only Match"]
```

The regex only matches strings with one or more of a single capital letter followed by 0 or more lowercase letters, a word boundary and optional spaces.

Note: try to avoid overwriting the builtin function `list()` and it's a good habit to always make regex strings raw.

Comment: This is the correct solution and this one is using regex, like i asked!  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do without regex:

```
l = ["This sentence should Not Match", "This Should Only Match"]
[s for s in l if s.istitle()]
```

Output:

```
['This Should Only Match']
```

Comment: I think you should be able to use `[s for s in l if s.istitle()]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try matching using `re.search` with the following pattern:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$
```

Script:

```
list = ["This sentence should Not Match", "This Should Only Match"]
matches = []
for l in list:
    x = re.search("^[A-Z][a-z]*(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)*$", l)
    if x:
        matches.append(l)

print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['This Should Only Match']
```

Comment: This is not the one I am looking for, as it matched with "HERE Is an example that Should NOT Match"

Comment: OP, It's a good idea to enumerate every possibility up front for future regex questions.